# http://localhost:8000/qconsole is not coming in MarkLogic 9 in browser

Tags: xquery, marklogic

In my system MarkLogic admin and config panel is working, but console panel is not. It worked until yesterday.
Message in browser shown below:

```
This site can't be reached
localhost refused to connect.
Did you mean http://localhost8000.com/?
Search Google for localhost 8000
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Are you sure MarkLogic is running? What OS are you on?

Comment: yes because http://localhost:8001/ and http://localhost:8002/nav/?type=databases both are coming, and os Windows 10 i am using.

Comment: Could you restart MarkLogic server and check once again? Please make sure, your port 8000 is not blocked.

Comment: @NavinRawat  I am new user and i didn't have any important data so i re installed mark logic now its ok. But if it will again come same, how can i check port is blocked and how to unblock? Thanks

Comment: If you have window system, you can follow http://www.howtonetworking.com/command/openport1.htm or anyother method which is easily available on net.

Answer (score 0):

Visit: `http://localhost:8000`

You are missing `:` for the port number in the URL.

Comment: It was typo, it is there in browser but still not coming.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `.htaccess` from the public folder to the root directory instead.

If you still have the problem then rename the file `server.php` in your root directory to `index.php`.